# curve_fit error when passing array as arguments for the p0 takes 2 positional arguments but 15 were given

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

Below is the example code to use curve_fit from the SciPy library in Python. Facing issue while passing the second argument of testLinear via curve_fit function. It works fine if I convert the second argument from an array to unpacked arguments. The idea to use an array instead of individual arguments is to make it parameterized. so that in the future if I want to include more parameters then I can adjust the number of coefficients easily instead of modifying the code. Please help in resolving this issue.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import sys, re, argparse, os, json

def column(matrix, i):
    return [row[i] for row in matrix]

inputs = [[62, 15, 25, 10, 14, 7.04, 16.88, 24.48, 427219, 648745, -3.067, 3081350.0, 2], [53, 14, 32, 0, 37, 28.12, 35.94, 22.37, 403760, 516128, 0.048, 2857308.0, 2]]
output = [50,60]
numP = len(inputs[0])
print("nump ",numP)
p = []
for i in range(0,int(numP)):
    p.append(column(inputs,i))
newX = np.vstack((p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3],p[4],p[5],p[6],p[7],p[8],p[9],p[10],p[11],p[12]))
#print("newX: ",newX)
def testLinear3(X,coefficients):
    p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3],p[4],p[5],p[6],p[7],p[8],p[9],p[10],p[11],p[12] = X
    c = []
    for i in range(0,len(coefficients)):
        c.append(coefficients[i])
    ret =  c[0]*p[0] + c[1]*p[1] + c[2]*p[2] + c[3]*p[3] + c[4]*p[4] + c[5]*p[5] + c[6]*p[6] + c[7]*p[7] + c[8]*p[8]+ c[9]*p[9] + c[10]*p[10] + c[11]*p[11] + c[12]*p[12] + c[13]
    return ret

#coefficients = np.array([2.0]*(13+1),dtype = float)
coefficients = [2.0]*(13+1)
popt,pcov = curve_fit(testLinear3,newX,output,coefficients)
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [281], in <cell line: 19>()
17 #coefficients = np.array([2.0]*(13+1),dtype = float)
18 coefficients = [2.0]*(13+1)
---> 19 popt,pcov = curve_fit(testLinear3,newX,output,coefficients)

483 def func_wrapped(params):
--> 484     return func(xdata, *params) - ydata

TypeError: testLinear3() takes 2 positional arguments but 15 were given
```

If I write the testLinear like below it works fine

```py
def testLinear2(X,c0,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,c13):
    p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3],p[4],p[5],p[6],p[7],p[8],p[9],p[10],p[11],p[12] = X
    ret = 0
    ret = c0 + c1*p[0] + c2*p[1] + c3*p[2] + c4*p[3] + c5*p[4] + c6*p[5] + c7*p[6] + c8*p[7]
    ret += c9*p[8]+ c10*p[9] + c11*p[10] + c12*p[11] + c13*p[12]
    return ret
```

Comment: try `curve_fit(testLinear3,newX,output,(coefficients,))` - pass a tuple.  See in the error line it is unpacking that `p0` arg when passing.

Comment: thanks for your reply, it didnt help, getting same error

Comment: I don't get your `positional` error, but rather `TypeError: The number of func parameters=14 must not exceed the number of data points=2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your function:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(lambda X, *coefficients: testLinear3(X, coefficients), newX, output, coefficients)
```

This is a guess, but since your code is not executable, I can't test it. Please include all data and imports to make your code run.

Comment: Thanks Matt for your input. I have fixed code to be executable.
I also tried your suggestions, but didnt help
    raise TypeError('Improper input: N=%s must not exceed M=%s' % (n, m))
TypeError: Improper input: N=14 must not exceed M=2

Comment: @Sainathreddykotla This error message means that you have more parameters in `curve_fit()` than you have data points. More information: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/14005

Comment: @Sainathreddykotla When that happens, it means that there can be multiple different sets of parameters that produce exactly the same fit. There are multiple ways to fix this. The simplest is to get more data. Alternatively, you can also use a regression method that can tolerate this, like LASSO. More information: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223486/modelling-with-more-variables-than-data-points

Comment: So it did solve the posted problem; there just happened to be another problem.

Comment: Thanks Matt yes indeed it worked!! thank you.
@NickODell Thanks for your input, with increased data set for inputs and output its working!